# How do I set NEO4J_AUTH environment variable and use it?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I'm trying to connect mongodb to neo4j and I have to set NEO4J_AUTH environment variable. How do I set it and use it in Windows?

I'm trying to follow the instructions from [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager/blob/master/docs/neo4j_doc_manager_doc.adoc#212-start-neo4j-and-mongo)

Comment: Use `set` instead of `export` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JonClements says, on Windows you use the `set` command to create/update/remove environment variables.

[Here is some official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754250(v=ws.11).aspx) for `set`.